# Calculating the standard deviation from a specified neighbourhood in a DEM in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculating the standardized topographic index position on GEE and I need to find a way to calculate standard deviation of a DEM. I see there is a focal statistics command for mean but I don't see one for standard deviation.

The formula I am trying to complete is:

(elevation of pixel - mean elevation of pixel within a specified radius)/Standard deviation of the elevation specified radius

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
var reduced = elevation
  .reduceNeighborhood({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
      .combine(ee.Reducer.stdDev(), null, true), 
    kernel: ee.Kernel.square(50, 'meters')
  })
  
var result = ee.Image().expression('(elevation - mean) / stdDev', {
  elevation: elevation,
  mean: reduced.select('elevation_mean'),
  stdDev: reduced.select('elevation_stdDev')
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cb3d8774be566e3899d3143a65abe2a2

Comment: Thanks this is great!